# socat - Forward to two Ports?

Tags: udp, socat

Is it possible to forward/fork a socat UDP listener to two ports?

I have the following which works with a single port:

```
socat -lf socat.log -u UDP4-LISTEN:55555,fork TCP:localhost:40111
```

but I also want to listen to set up another port to make the original UDP available as well.

Is it possible to fork to two separate local host ports?

Something like `socat -lf socat.log -u UDP4-LISTEN:55555,fork TCP:localhost:40111, fork UDP4:localhost:40112`  or so?